# What's the scope of a proxy created by Spring AOP?

Tags: spring, spring-aop

Diving deeper into Spring AOP I already understood that Spring Framework chooses a proxy-based strategy for weaving in aspects. I read that these Proxies are created at runtime and just in time, i.e. "lazy".

Now the following question came up to me: **Which scope does such a proxy object have**, considering a web appliaction? Is there a way to find out?

I'm looking forward to your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proxies are usually created by a `BeanPostprocessor` (in `AbstractAutoProxyCreator` hirearchy) so them have the same scope as the target bean.

If you create proxies by other ways, like using a `ProxyFactoryBean` you can change the scope, but in general isn't a good idea.